# Mac nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (48: Address already in use)

Tags: reactjs, go, nginx

I am using Nginx to run both the frontend and backend from the same PC.

Frontend: React   (localhost:3000)

Backend : GO-Lang (localhost:8080)

You can expect [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error when you try to access BE APIs from your FE code.

To overcome this I used nginx to create proxies for FE and BE on Different routes but on the same port (localhost:8000)

FE: /

BE: /server

nginx.conf

```
upstream server {
server localhost:8080;
}

upstream client {
server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location ~ /server/(?<section>.*) {
        rewrite ^/server/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://server;
       
    }
}
```

I stopped the nginx with `sudo nginx -s stop`

Closed terminal

Quit terminal completely

But didn't shut down my PC

1. Today I tried some other configs with the same port (8000) and got the error mentioned in the title.
2. So used a different port everything worked as expected.
3. But when I reverted my config to the above config again. It is showing the error mentioned in the title.

**The problem**

1. What I observed is all the ports I used in step 2 are occupied now and I am not able to use them although I have stopped all the servers earlier.
2. After reverting back to the initial config even though the port I am trying to use is 8000 it still says that the port is occupied.

**How can I use my port 8000 again?**

Answer (score 1):

### Kill the process in Activity Monitor

1. `sudo nginx` starts a process
2. Run `ps -ef | grep nginx` to know the running nginx processes.
3. As you can see in the image attached when I stopped the service using `sudo nginx -s stop` 2 lines are missing in the search returned by `ps -ef | grep nginx` ( I am not sure about the last line that is common in both the results. I am guessing that it must be something related to the search )
4. This probably means that I am able to stop the process successfully ✅

> [image]

### Solution here

1. Run `ps -ef | grep nginx`. If you can see some processes running even after stopping the process it might be that the process didn't stop properly
2. To terminate/ kill it properly
3. Go to Activity Monitor ( search for activity monitor in Mac Spotlight search )
4. Go to Network
5. Search for `nginx` and quit them all.
6. In some cases you won't find `nginx` in network
7. Then go to CPU and search for `nginx`.
8. You must find some `nginx` processes consuming CPU.
9. Quit them all.
10. Now try running `sudo nginx`. Everything should work as expected. ✅

> [image]